# Driver USB debugging with tablet in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I´m developing in android with ecplipse, in Windows 7, 32bit, the tablet is AOC MW0931, is the new model, I try modify the file "android_winusb.inf", the hardware Id, for this table are:

- USB\VID_2207&PID_0006
- USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006&REV_0222
- USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01
- USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&REV_0222&MI_01

But the IDE does not recognize the tablet to debug. what kind hardware can I use for this device?? How can I modify correctly the file?

Thi's the String file:

```
    ;AOC Breeze MW0931 ADB
    %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006
    %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006&REV_0222
    %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01
    %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&REV_0222&MI_01
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if ADB is detecting, guessing it probably isn't by going to the command prompt and typing `adb devices` (assuming sdk tools are in your PATH).

Installing PDANet (http://junefabrics.com/android/) may be useful as well, I quite often have an issue with installing the ADB driver but PDANet installs the driver and its always worked for me.

Comment: with PDANet recognize the device in windows, but the IDE(eclipse) not yet

Comment: I try with all driver (HTC, SAMSUMNG, OTHER..), but nothing

Comment: Does ``adb devices`` show anything in the command prompt. Is USB debugging enabled on your device. or if you go into device manager does it show the ADB driver is installed